# Change instance every ten instance along curve - how to use Index?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am looking for a way to place instances on a curve every 10cm. I also want to be able to use an instance "Cube" 9 times and then one Cylinder instance. Repeatedly along the curve.

Image a railing. [image: Railing]

For now, in the image below, I use an Integer (top, left) to simulate an index value so that the instance used is switched each time the integer reaches 10, 20, 30,...

My question is: How to replace the Integer by a (set of) node that is an index of every points on the curve? How would you do that?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

[image: Working Geometry Node]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should put instances in one stack and then use instance index to select the right one:

[image]

Comment: You ROCK!  Thank you!  :-)   It works with curves, too.